# Ubuntu 14.04: no sound card detected AMD

Tags: 14.04, sound

So all I have is a dummy output for the sound, and have tried many different solutions with no luck so far. Most recently I looked here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

The quick question is, where do I find my sound card driver name for:

```
sudo modprobe snd-[NAME OF YOUR SOUNDCARD'S DRIVER]
```

Other possibly useful information:

In terminal, when I enter:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd
```

It gives me:

```
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-page-alloc.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-device.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
```

I believe that I'm supposed to have an AMD sound card driver (https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/sound/4844/sound:TrinityHDMIAudioController/).

Terminal:

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
```

Gives:

```
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 22c7
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at feb44000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

Flags : bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 22c7
Flags: slow devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at feb40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 22c7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... doing Ubuntu updates did the trick. I hadn't done that in a while...